# Why can’t I access router settings? Default gateway not working as expected?

Tags: networking, router, gateway

I saw this was a common issue but I couldn't really find something that applied to my specific case: I have reset the router and my PC and it doesn't really seem to help.

My default gateway and the way I used to access the settings on my router used to be `192.168.1.1` however for some reason that doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

These are my results from running `ipconfig -all`:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   ...
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.239.94.133(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.239.92.1
```

I tried accessing the default gateway on the browser instead but still no luck, everything else seems to be working normally, is there any way I can access the router?

Comment: According to your `ipconfig -all`, your default gateway is `10.239.92.1`. Try visiting http://10.239.92.1 in your browser.

Comment: as noted on the post i tried so but no luck :c

Comment: Have you changed your router into bridge mode (perhaps there's a physical flip switch on it)? (And the IP shown above is a CGNAT IP assigned by your ISP?)

Comment: What do you mean by "everything else seems to be working normally"? Please be more specific!

Comment: What do you see when you try to access the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were/are using DHCP? If so, your DHCP server (probably integrated with the router) does not work anymore.

I also assume `192.168.1.1` was the original IP address of the router (if so it should still be the same after a reset).

You need to set up your network configuration manually:

- disconnect all devices from your router
- manually set the network card on your client to `192.168.1.2` (the subnet mask should be the same one your router has, probably 24 bit)
- connect the client to your router

Now you should be able to access the router via `192.168.1.1` again.

Note: What do you mean by "everything else seems to be working normally"? Please be more specific!